# Java - Search performantly for subset of String in String list

Tags: java, android, string, search

I want to search through a list of Strings and return the values, which contains which contain the search string.

The list could look like this (can have up to 1000 entries). Although it is not guranteed that it is always letters and then a digit. It could be digits only, words only or even both mixed up:

```
entry 1
entry 2
entry 3
entry 4
test 1
test 2
test 3
tst 4
```

If the user does search for 1, these should be returned:

```
entry 1
test 1
```

The situation is that the user has a search bar and can enter a search string. This search string is used to search through the list.

How can this be done performantly?

Currently, I have got:

```
for (String s : strings) {
    if (s.contains(searchedText))   result.add(s);
}
```

It is O(N) and really slow. Especially if the user types many characters at a time.

Comment: Do you only want to search for numbers or for any combination of letters and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the upper limit of the number in the string and if you have no concerns about space, use an Array of ArrayLists where the array index is the number of the string:

```
ArrayList<String>[] data = new ArrayList<String>[1000];
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
  data[i] = new ArrayList<String>();

//inserting data
int num = Integer.parseInt(datastring.substring(datastring.length-1));
data[i].add(datastring);

//getting all data that has a 1
for ( String s: data[1] )
  result.add(s);
```

Using a Hashmap would overwrite previous mapped values when trying to put new values into it. 
i.e. if 1 maps to entry, then you try to add 1 mapping to test, the entry would get replaced with test.

As another idea, you could just keep a count of the number of strings with each number, so when you're searching, you know how many to look for, so as soon as you find all of them, you stop searching:

```
int[] str_count = new int[1000];
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
  str_count[i] = 0;

//when storing data into the list:
int num = Integer.parseInt(datastring.substring(datastring.length-1));
str_count[i]++;

//when searching the list for 1s:
int count = str_count[1];
for (String s : strings) {
  if (s.contains(searchedText))   
    result.add(s);
  if (result.size() == count)
    break;
}
```

While the first idea would be much faster, it would take up more space. Yet, the second idea takes up less space, the worst case scenario would search O(N) still.

Comment: Why do you use Vector and not ArrayList? Keep in mind that Vector is synchronized and thus slower.

Comment: I'll fix that. I had no preference because I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but as you know n Java, String objects are immutable, but also can represent collection(array) of chars. So one thing what you can do is to perform search with better  algorithms as [binary_search](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/searching/binarysearch.html), [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm), [Rabin–Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm), [Boyer–Moore string search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), [StringSearch](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/) or [one of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm). Also you may consider some usage of [Abstract_data_types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) with better performance (hashing, trees etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple if you use streams:

```java
final List<String> items = Arrays.asList("entry 1", "entry 2", "entry 3", "test 1", "test 2", "test 3");
final String searchString = "1";
final List<String> results = items.parallelStream()  // work in parallel
        .filter(s -> s.contains(searchString))       // pick out items that match
        .collect(Collectors.toList());               // and turn those into a result list
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Notice the `parallelStream()` which will cause the list to be filtered and traversed using all available CPUs.

In your case you can use the `results` when the user expands the search term (while typing) to reduce the amount of items that need to be filtered, because if 's' matches all items in result, all those that match 'se' will be a sub-list of result.

Comment: Reusing the results can be dangerous if you don't take corrections into account, but can significantly increase performance.

Comment: I am bound to Android and there is no Java 8.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part about Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any additional structures,  you cannot perform faster, than look though your data. That takes O(N).
If you can do some preparations, like building text index, you can increase performance of search. General information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search. If you can make some assumptions about your data (like the last symbol is number and you are going to search only by it), it'll be easy to create such index.